# Transporting files over direct mail

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Our company is in need of some good methods on transporting confidential files over the mail (UPS/Fedex ect).

I was thinking about a password protected jump drive but what do you guys feel is the best method/industry standard?

The information contains social security numbers and will be between 2-20GB databases.

Thanks!

Comment: Setup truecrypt on your favorite storage device?  Transmit the key/password for the volume over separate channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember the government sends classified information through the US Postal Service.  The item must be first wrapped in plain brown wrapping probably with some tamper detect and then put in to the mailing envelope.  Then the mail is sent REGISTERED with RETURN RECEIPT REQUESTED and with a signature required (it might have to be sent and signed by a specific person).  Thus there is tracking of where things went and the "package" is locked away each night in a secured area.

If the government uses this process for classified material, I'm sure its probably safe for transmission of unclassified but protected and sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a [IronKey Enterprise](https://www.ironkey.com/enterprise).  With remote terminate and user activity, sounds like a winner to me.  However their biggest key is 16GB at the moment.

Comment: Thanks guys! Do you know if there is a standard data transportation method? Like a link with the run down. I have been looking but unable to find it.